# How to create file uploading with a possibility of adding files again and again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, frontend

I'm trying to do something like such interface showed on the following image. Clicking on the Plus I want to be able to select multiple images and show them within the squares. Then, I want to click on the Plus again and add a few more images, and show them in the new portion of squares. I wanna let user select such number of files that he wants.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR3uJ.png)

For now I've found solution for single file:

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

```html
<script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Comment: perhaps you need to add another button named like 'Add',

Comment: Perhaps the [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-multiple) attribute is an option to consider?

Comment: Using [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_object_URLs) is better then using base64, synchronous, faster & less memory footprint

Comment: @Endless how to send files by submit in this case? wish to draw attention that I need to send not only images, I have also text fields in my form

Comment: use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for that, append all text/blob/file that you need and send the formData with ajax.

You could just do: `new FormData(formElement)` also

Answer (score 0):

```
let files = []; // once

if (input.files) {
    let files = [...files, ...input.files];
}
```